# Is it possible for jquery to search all inputs with a CSS class of '.map'?

Tags: jquery

Just wondering, could jQuery search for all inputs that have a CSS class of '.map' and return the ID and class of the input into an array?

Example:

if I have the following input on my page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" CssClass="mapTest" />
<asp:TextBox ID="test1" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" CssClass="mapTest1" />
<asp:TextBox ID="test2" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" CssClass="mapTest2" />
<asp:TextBox ID="test3" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" CssClass="mapTest3" />
```

Is it possible for jQuery to format the result in an array as below?

```
testArr[0] = 'test-mapTest';
testArr[1] = 'test1-mapTest1';
testArr[2] = 'test2-mapTest2';
testArr[3] = 'test3-mapTest3';
```

Also, in .net I have to use the following code `<%= test.ClientID %>` then it will only able to get me the correct ID number, so I'm not sure how can I in jquery then will only able to get the correct ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it is!

```
var my_array = [];
$(":input[class^=map]").each(function(index, element) {
  my_array.push(element.attr("id") + "-" + element.attr("class"));
});
```

The above example uses jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method for accessing the element's id and class attributes, solely for illustration purposes. It's often faster and easier to read to access an element's built-in attributes directly:

```
var my_array = [];
$(":input[class^=map]").each(function(index, element) {
    my_array.push(this.id + "-" + this.className);
});
```

Comment: they dont actually have a map class though, but rather classes with the term "map" in them.

Comment: That will not match any of his inputs because they all contain map in the class name but the class name doesn't match exactly to map.  Would need to use ^=

Comment: Thanks. Should have read closer. Has been edited to reflect that fact.

Comment: @Alex: I tried the code, but error message 'Object doesn't support this property or method' display :(

Comment: @JinYong There's nothing in the above code that would throw that error. Perhaps edit your question with the code that is throwing that error? Sounds like a seperate issue.

Comment: @Alex: cool... the 2nd code is working ... woh ... u r the superman .. :)

Comment: @Alex: will the above code work for dropdown box as well?? This seem like doesn't get the ID and CssClass for the dorpdown box.. :(, How can I do so that it will retrieve both input and dropdown box ID and Css Class?

Comment: @JinYong: I have edited my answer to work for dropdown boxes as well. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

The following selector will match each of your map inputs: `$("input[class^=map]")`. It will match any input which has a class which starts with `map`. You can then pull everything from there that you need.

Answer (score 3):

Your question states...

> Just wondering, could jQuery search for all inputs that have a CSS class of '.map'

So I answered...

```
var results = [];

$(':input.map').each(function() {
   results.push(this.id + '-' + this.className);
});
```

But then your example data shows the classes matched are `mapTest` for example, which isn't a class of `map`. You'd need to change the selector to `:input[class^=map]`.

Answer (score 1):

Search for all the inputs, check if they have a class containing the string `"map"` and put them in an array if they do:

```
  var testArr = [];
  $.each($("input"), function(){
   var thisInput = $(this);
   if(thisInput.attr("class").indexOf("map"){
    testArr.push(thisInput.attr("id") + "-" + thisInput.attr("class"));
   }
  });
```

Comment: You could also use $('input').each(function() {...});